# How to accessing indices in an array at transition in an array from one to another value (python)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like:

```
val=[[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]]
```

I would like to access the indices where the value changes from 1 to 0.

Expected output is like:

```
    [[(2,3),(4,5),(6,7)],[(0,1),(3,4),(4,5),(6,7)]]
```

I tried with np.gradient function, and able to find the gradient value. Instead of this is any better method:

```
X=np.gradient(val,axis=1)
Y=np.gradient(val,axis=0)
         
trans_YX = np.array(list(zip(Y.ravel(),X.ravel())),dtype('f4,f4')).reshape(Y.shape)
```

Current output:

```
[[(-1.,  0. ) ( 0.,  0. ) ( 0., -0.5) ( 1., -0.5) ( 0.,  0.5) ( 0.,  0.5)
  ( 0., -0.5) ( 0., -0.5) ( 0.,  0. ) ( 0.,  0. )]
 [(-1.,  1. ) ( 0.,  0.5) ( 0.,  0. ) ( 1., -0.5) ( 0.,  0. ) ( 0.,  0.5)
  ( 0., -0.5) ( 0., -0.5) ( 0.,  0. ) ( 0.,  0. )]]
```

Comment: Is the *numpy* specific/related?   In other words, pure Python is fine too?

Comment: its numpy specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a semi-numpy solution:

```
val = [[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]]

a = np.array(val)

mask = a[:, :-1] != a[:, 1:]
# array([[False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False]])

idx = np.arange(mask.shape[1])
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

out = [list(zip((x:=idx[m]), x+1)) for m in mask]
```

output: `[[(2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)], [(0, 1), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7)]]`

Answer (score 1):

If pure python works for our solution. you can apply the methodology to each row:

```
[(i, i + 1) for i in range(len((val_row)) - 1) if val_row[i] != val_row[i+1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please notice you indices are `x` and `x+1` so one must look for `x` itself.

Here `numpy.diff` can get the difference between value and neighboring value. Using `numpy.where` one can find the indices of some specific conditions (such as no equal to `0`)

Next you can organize the results:

```
import numpy as np

val=[[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]]

result = [
    [
        (i, i + 1)
        for i in np.where(np.diff(each) != 0)[0]
    ]
    for each in val
]

print(result)
```